# Pass the same parameter to multiple tests

Tags: testing, elixir

How do I pass the same parameter to different tests in Elixir?
Now I calculate it in every test. Is it possible to calculate this parameter once before starting tests and pass it to each test?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ExUnit.Callbacks.setup/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup/1) or [`ExUnit.Callbacks.setup_all/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html?#setup_all/1)

```rb
setup_all do
  [my_param: 42]
end

test "global context", %{my_param: value} do
  assert 42 == value
end
```